# Bullet is always being fired from the static position

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, frame-rate, raycasting

I'm creating a FPS Game. I have a firepoint gameobject which is the child of the Player. With firepoint as a reference, I'm firing bullets. Following is my code,

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public float moveSpeed, gravityModifier, jumpPower, runSpeed =12f;
    public CharacterController charCon;

    private Vector3 moveInput;

    public Transform camTrans;

    public float mouseSensitivity;
    public bool invertX;
    public bool invertY;

    private bool canJump, canDoubleJump;
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    public Animator anim;

    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform firePoint;
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        // store y velocity

        float yStore = moveInput.y;
        
        Vector3 vertMove = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 horiMove = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        moveInput = horiMove + vertMove ;
        moveInput.Normalize();
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveInput = moveInput * runSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveInput = moveInput * moveSpeed;
        }

        moveInput.y = yStore;
        moveInput.y += Physics.gravity.y * gravityModifier * Time.deltaTime;

        if (charCon.isGrounded)
        {
            moveInput.y = Physics.gravity.y * gravityModifier * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        canJump = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckPoint.position, 0.25f, whatIsGround).Length> 0;
        
        if (canJump)
        {
            canDoubleJump = false;
        }
        
        //handle jumping
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            moveInput.y = jumpPower;

            canDoubleJump = true;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canDoubleJump)
        {
            moveInput.y = jumpPower;

            canDoubleJump = false;

        }
        
        charCon.Move(moveInput*  Time.deltaTime);
        
        //Control Camera Rotation
        Vector2 mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y")) * mouseSensitivity;
        if (invertX)
        {
            mouseInput.x = -mouseInput.x;
        }

        if (invertY)
        {
            mouseInput.y = -mouseInput.y;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + mouseInput.x,
            transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
        
        camTrans.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(camTrans.rotation.eulerAngles + new Vector3(-mouseInput.y,0f,0f));
        
        //Handle Shooting

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(camTrans.position, camTrans.forward, out hit,50f))
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(camTrans.position, hit.point) > 2f)
                {
                    firePoint.LookAt(hit.point);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                firePoint.LookAt(camTrans.position + (camTrans.forward * 30f));
            }
            Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.transform.position,firePoint.transform.rotation);
        }
        
        anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed",moveInput.magnitude);
        anim.SetBool("onGround",canJump);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the bullet is always being fired from the same position though firepoint is the child of the Player. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

Following is the code that is attached to the bullet prefab.

```
    public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed, lifeTime;
    
        public Rigidbody theRB;
    
        public GameObject impactEffect;
      
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            theRB.velocity = Vector3.forward * moveSpeed;
            lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    
            if (lifeTime <= 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position + (transform.forward * (-moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)), transform.rotation);
        }
    }
```

Following is the code that is controls the camera,

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
   
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = target.position;
        transform.rotation = target.rotation;
    }
}
```

Following is my scene,

[image]

`BulletController` is attached to the bullet prefab. `CameraController` is attached to the MainCamera. `PlayerController` is attached to the Player game object.

Comment: Where are the transforms being assigned?  What *is* `firePoint` assigned to?

Comment: (0.366,-0.349,1.2) is the transform that it is assigned and the bullets always originates from this point even if I turn around and move.

Comment: Yes, but the code you've posted - I'm assuming something else is *setting* these variables?  Does the fact that `firePoint` *is* a `Transform`, and you're calling `firePoint.Transform` make a difference?  I think we need to see more.

Comment: @Moo-Juice please see the updated question. I have added the code completely.

Comment: I have also added the screenshots and explained it  :)

Comment: I strongly recommend you split up your `Update` method into individual methods for better group what belongs together and maintain individual parts of your behavior ... e.g. `HandleMoving`, `HandleJumping`, `HandleShooting` .. would make it also better to read / focus for us